# 3d symmetric random walk passes infinitely through any particular line

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

I'm trying to solve problem 27 from Chapter XIV An Introduction to Probability Theory Volume I by William Feller, http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/An-Introduction-to-probability-Theory-by-William-Feller.pdf:

> 27. In a three-dimensional symmetric random walk the particle has probability one to pass infinitely often through any particular line $x=m, y=n.$ (Hint: See Problem 5)

Here is problem 5

> 5. Consider a random walk in which the particle starts at the origin and moves a unit step to the right or left, or stays at its present position with probabilities $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, respectively ($\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1)$. Let $A,B>0$. Find $P(\text{the random walk reaches } A \text{ before } -B)$ and $E(\text{number of steps until the particle leaves } (-B,A)).$

I am really stuck here. I don't really know how problem 5 factors into this problem at all.

I am pretty sure that $$P(\text{the random walk reaches } A \text{ before } -B)=\frac{r^B-1}{r^{A+B}-1},$$
where $r=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$, and 
$$
E(\text{number of steps until the particle leaves } (-B,A))=\frac{B}{1-2p}-\frac{A+B}{1-2p}\frac{r^B-1}{r^{A+B}-1},
$$
again where $r=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$.

I appreciate any help with solving 27.

Thanks!

Comment: The hint might allude to the fact that, if (X,Y,Z) is a 3-dimensional simple random walk, then the process (X,Y) performs a delayed random walk with probability one-third to stay at the current vertex. But (X,Y) passes infinitely often by any point (m,n) if and only if the corresponding undelayed process, which happens to be a 2-dimensional simple random walk, does. Hence, if one knows that the 2-dimensional simple random walk is recurrent, one knows that (X,Y,Z) passes infinitely often through any line x=m, y=n, almost surely.

Comment: So I know that an undelayed 2d simple random walk is recurrent. Why does this imply that the delayed 2d random walk is recurrent? Do you possibly have a reference for this fact?

Comment: The delayed random walk is recurrent because it passes by every state the undelayed random walk passes by, only, more slowly, hence in particular it passes again by its starting point.